# Make comments with Vim that live normally with the 'go fmt' tool

Tags: vim, go

Golang has a tool that's called 'gofmt' which formats your code. I'm using the `vim-go` plugin which fires the 'gofmt' tool every time when I save a file.

Golang uses tabs for indention. I marked the tabs as `[  ]` in the following examples.

Here's a problem which I've run:

I have the following code:

```
func main() {
[  ]if true {
[  ][  ]do.Something()
[  ]}
}
```

I need to comment the `if` clause.
So, if I comment it like the following(I'm using `nerd-commenter`):

```
func main() {
//[  ]if true {
//[  ][  ]do.Something()
//[  ]}
}
```

Gofmt formats it to:

```
func main() {
[  ]//[  ]if true {
[  ]//[  ][  ]do.Something()
[  ]//[  ]}
}
```

If I do this:

```
func main() {
[  ]//if true {
[  ][  ]//do.Something()
[  ]//}
}
```

Gofmt formats it to this:

```
func main() {
[  ]//if true {
[  ]//do.Something()
[  ]//}
}
```

I need to comment the `if` clause like the following:

```
func main() {
[  ]//if true {
[  ]//[  ]do.Something()
[  ]//}
}
```

Then Gofmt won't change the commented block.
How I can do this?

Comment: The aim of gofmt is to make all go code look the same. If you want your code to be formatted differently, don't use gofmt

Comment: @Mark I'm afraid that you didn't understand my question. I want to make Vim to make comments in the same format as gofmt formatting.

Comment: Sorry, I did misunderstand. I use vimgo with gofmt and it formats as in your final example, regardless of the number of preceding tabs. Perhaps some other plugin is interfering with gofmt?

Answer (score 2):

The way I do this is with block mode insertion.

- Put your cursor on the `i` of `if`.
- Press `<C-v>` to start insert mode, then `jj` to move it down two lines.
- Press `I` to enter "Visual-Block insert", which will insert text at the start of the block selection for every line (see [`v_b_I`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/visual.txt.html#v_b_I)).
- Press `//<Esc>` to add `//` and leave visual block insert mode.

Which should give you exactly what you want:

[image]